# MediaRecorder - Not able to change output type to File Descriptor

Tags: android, video-streaming, mediarecorder

My objective is to create a streaming application. I want to stream the device screen on a web application written in Angular. Previously I had created a functionality using MediaRecorder which records the screen and saves the data to a file. From what I have read and researched, I found out to stream the screen I can use LocalSocket instead of File with MediaRecorder and pass FileDescriptor in the setFileOutput method of MediaRecorder.

When i implement it, It gives the following exception:

> W/pplication12345: type=1400 audit(0.0:19217): avc: denied { read
> write } for path="socket:[1725434]" dev="sockfs" ino=1725434
> scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0
> tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c25,c257,c512,c768
> tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
>
> E/MediaRecorder: prepare failed: -38
>
> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Following is the code snippet:

```
LocalServerSocket server;
LocalSocket receiver;
Int BUFFER_SIZE = 500000;
LocalSocket sender;

server = new LocalServerSocket(“NET.STREAMING-”);
receiver = new LocalSocket();
receiver.connect(server.getLocalSocketAddress());
receiver.setReceiveBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
sender = server.accept();
sender.setSendBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE); 
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); //THREE_GPP  
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(sender.getFileDescriptor());   
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(16); // 30   
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);    
Int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();    
int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

I am using the latest API 29.